# Does the Law of the Excluded Middle imply syntactical completeness?

Tags: logic, incompleteness, nonclassical-logic

The Law of the Excluded Middle (LEM) states that for any proposition $p$, we have $\vdash p \lor \lnot p $.

Syntactic completeness (a.k.a negation completeness) states that for any proposition $p$, we have $\vdash p$ or $\vdash \lnot p$.

As far as I'm aware, in classical propositional logic the former implies the latter (what's the simplest way to justify this?). This is highly problematic though, because it would mean that the contrapositive LEM is false) renders classical (Peano) arithmetic inconsistent – that is, LEM cannot possibly be a valid axiom/rule.

This strikes me as plain wrong, from what I've read. So, where have I messed up in my reasoning? Can we not in fact say that $\vdash p \lor \lnot p $ implies $\vdash p$ or $\vdash \lnot p $, at least not for classical logic? It seems intuitively true, but since I'm struggling to justify it formally, perhaps this is where the mistake lies.

Comment: Propositional variable is neither provable nor refutable even if $p\lor \lnot p$ is provable. You might misunderstand the completeness.

Comment: As far as I know, there are two completeness in logic and they are not coincide. When we call a theory $T$ is complete, every sentence (over the language of $T$) is provable or refutable from $T$. However when we say a logical system $\mathcal{L}$ is complete, it means (semantic) satisfiability implies (synthetic) provability.

Comment: The two notions are different : the so-called semantic completeness for e.g. propositional calculus says that "if $\varphi$ is *valid* (i.e. a tautology), then it is *provable*". Thus, $p \lor \lnot p$ being a tautology, is provable; but $p$ is **not** a tautlogy (for any $p$), and thus it is not provable. Negation-completeness says that "for every sentence $\varphi$, either $\varphi$ or $\lnot \varphi$ is provable". Propositional logic, like first-order logic, are **not** negation-complete.

Comment: This is a crucial difference between truth and provability.  Yes, $\phi\lor \psi$ is true iff at least one of $\phi$ and $\psi$ is true.  But we may have that $\phi\lor \psi$ be provable while neither of $\phi$ and $\psi$ is provable.  This should be intuitive: you know by pure logic that I'm either sitting or not sitting, but, you know neither that I'm sitting nor that I'm not.

Comment: There is another confusion between truth and provability in the third paragraph.  Even granted (what is not the case) that derivability of LEM did imply negation-completeness, then negation-incompleteness would still only imply that LEM is not derivable.  But the unprovability of $p\lor \neg p$ does not imply the provability of $\neg (p\lor \neg p)$.  Of course there are well-studied (consistent!) systems where LEM is not derivable.

Comment: @tetori: I specifically referred to syntactic (negation) completeness here. Semantic completeness does not come into it anywhere. And in fact, there are even more than 2 notions of completeness.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: Sure, I understand this (perhaps you were explaining to @tetori?). I'm not sure where that's relevant to the question though.

Comment: @mmw Can LEM hold but not be derivable though?

Comment: @mmw Also, I think I see what you mean by your first point. I was thinking in terms of constructive (at least intuitionistic) logic, where that statement about provability of the components of a disjunction *must* hold. In classical logic though, I suppose it doesn't necessarily hold! (I'm not sure where exactly the crucial difference lies though.)

Comment: @Noldorin - sorry for my insistence : the fact that $\vdash p \lor \lnot p$ but **not** $\vdash p$ or $\vdash \lnot p$ is due **exactly** to the soundenss and completeness of classical prop logic. If $\vdash p$ or $\vdash \lnot p$, this means that either $p$ or $\lnot p$ is a *tautology*, which is **not**, as already said in the answer and comments.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: Ah, thanks for clarifying. If $p$ is a sentence though, surely $\vdash p \lor \lnot p$ implies $\vdash p$ or $\vdash \lnot p$. (BTW I don't see an answer from you, only a couple of comments.)

Comment: I think my confusion here comes from conflating 'sentences' and 'propositions'... I'm still not sure on the exact difference, mind you.

Comment: @Noldorin - **NO** again. Consider first order logic : clearly $\vdash \forall x P(x) \lor \lnot \forall x P(x)$ but neither $\vdash \forall x P(x)$ nor $\vdash \lnot \forall x P(x)$, because the two last *sentences* are **not** valid and so (again by *completeness*) not provable.

Comment: How odd! I'm so used to intuitionistic logic, where you can conclude this, no problem.

Comment: I think the above is because, viewing this problem from the perspective of natural deduction, if there's a proof of $A \lor B$ then there must be a proof of $A$ or a proof of $B$ somewhere above. That's in intuitionistic logic. But with the LEM, in classical logic, I guess this argument doesn't work because $A \lor B$ could be deduced via the LEM and not directly. Right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume you already know the answer to your own question by now, but for completeness...

The key point is that syntactic completeness is a property of a formal system $S$ as viewed from the **meta-system**. Just because $S \vdash p \lor \neg p$ does not imply that $S \vdash p$ or $S \vdash \neg p$. The former "$\lor$" is a symbol in the language of the formal system, while the latter "or" is a part of the language of the meta-system. They only coincide for semantics, namely $M \vDash p \lor \neg p$ iff $M \vDash p$ or $M \vDash \neg p$ if $M$ is a structure and $p$ is a sentence over $M$. But if there are different models of $S$ that disagree on some sentence $p$, and $S$ is sound, then necessarily $S$ cannot prove $p$ and cannot prove $\neg p$, since whatever $S$ proves must be true for every model of $S$.

Comment: Yes, but thanks for the clarification anyway. As I understand, $\vdash p \lor \neg p$ does imply $\vdash p$ or $\vdash \neg p$ for a given $p$, in any system of constructive logic.

Comment: @Noldorin: It's not just for constructive logic. It's for any formal system that can interpret PA$^-$, including strong classical set theories like ZFC or strong type theories like MLTT or weak arithmetic theories like Q. But if I'm not mistaken intuitionistic first-order logic does satisfy that $\vdash p \lor \neg p$ iff $\vdash p$ or $\vdash \neg p$, because the only way you can derive a disjunction is by the introduction rule since intuitionistic logic forbids double negation elimination or LEM, and the principle of explosion can only be used under impossible (unprovable) assumptions.

Comment: @Noldorin: I checked https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic and my claim is correct; search for "(DP)" for the disjunction property of intuitionistic logic. =)

Comment: I see. What's $PA^-$, some variant of Peano Arithmetic? I presume that although you say ZFC, it must still be in a constructive setting, else it would contradict what you and others have said above. :)

Comment: @Noldorin: PA$^-$ is described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Equivalent_axiomatizations). And no, ZFC is full ZFC, but I misread your comment as "does not imply". Haha! So I was indeed saying that any formal system that can interpret classical arithmetic does **not** satisfy the disjunction property. Thanks for catching my misreading!

Comment: Oh right, all clear. :)

Comment: Oh sorry. Gladly accepted.

Comment: Thanks, @user21820  I'm back on chat.  I'll delete my earlier comments here, and later come back to delete this one too.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of sentences of classical propositional logic that are neither provable nor refutable.  The simplest is $p$, where $p$ is a proposition letter.

Comment: That's not a sentence, since it has a free variable. It's an open formula.